# Getting the ClaimsPrincipal or ClaimsIdentity from inside ASP.NET Core dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I have a class that has `ClaimsIdentity` as a dependency like so:

> public ClaimsIdentityDecorator(ClaimsIdentity identity)

That is supposed to be the Claimsidentity of the current user. I retrieve it like via the `IHttpContextAccessor` like so:

```cs
services.AddScoped( x=>
{
    var context =  x.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    return context.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
});
```

I need to inspect a users claims, and it would seem that ClaimsIdentity or ClaimsPrincipal or some other identity object would be automatically injected for me. Retrieving it from the HttpContext and adding it myself is fine. However, if there is another object or interface that has claims on it that's already there, I would like to design my classes to take that dependency.

Also, I just want to make sure this should be injected at the Scope level.

Comment: Why not just inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into the dependent classes and extract he user from the context as needed.

Comment: @Nkosi because I just want the current user, and his claims. not the entire http context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no built in way to provide a `ClaimsIdentity` that I'm aware of, but you probably want `AddTransient`. If a user logs out, but the instance was created at the beginning of the request `AddScoped` won't reflect that change.